# EarthEngine: how to rename output of reducer, with multiple bands?

Tags: google-earth-engine, reducers, reduceregion

I would like to change the output name of a reducer, ideally by appending "_prefix" on each band. `setOutputs()` function does it (partially) when there is only one band, but not when there are multiple bands? Can I use `setOutputs()` for multiple bands, or do I need to do some `map()`?

And as a bonus question, why does `setOutputs()` work with `reduceRegions()`, but not with `reduceRegion()`?

Code ([link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/6d375bfbf6a4c4e36b8dd7c460d2263a)):

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[[-103.1431, 37.7422],
          [-103.1431, 37.6291],[-102.9371, 37.6291],[-102.9371, 37.7422]]]);

var TCL_1 = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection("IDAHO_EPSCOR/TERRACLIMATE").first()).select(["tmmx", "tmmn"])


// TEST: on one image 
var res_out = TCL_1.select(["tmmn"]).reduceRegion({
   geometry: geometry,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean().setOutputs(["mean"]),
  scale: 5000,
  crs: "EPSG:4326"
})

var res_out_FC = TCL_1.select(["tmmn"]).reduceRegions({
   collection: ee.FeatureCollection(ee.Feature(geometry)),
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean().setOutputs(["mean"]),
  scale: 5000,
  crs: "EPSG:4326"
})

var res_out_FC_2Bands = TCL_1.select(["tmmx", "tmmn"]).reduceRegions({
   collection: ee.FeatureCollection(ee.Feature(geometry)),
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean().setOutputs(["_mean"]),
  scale: 5000,
  crs: "EPSG:4326"
})


print(res_out, "Mean F")
print(res_out_FC, "Mean FC")
print(res_out_FC_2Bands, "Mean FC 2 bands")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both `reduceRegion` and `reduceRegions`, single input reducers are automatically replicated to match the number of input bands (by explicitly calling forEachBand() for you, automatically).

When that occurs, the output name is ignored because it can't be (re)used for each of the outputs.  In a slight inconsistency, this replication and renaming scheme happens even if there's only one band in `reduceRegion` but only if there are multiple bands in `reduceRegions`.

Comment: great, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: thanks for the answer, I ended up in the exact same situation and I wanted to know if this could become a feature request ?